# Screen resolution iOS Devices and graphics

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

Heyho,

Each iOS device has a different screen resolution and pixel density.

Why do I need to support **non-retina and retina graphics only** and dont make graphics for each different screensize (e.g. 4 graphics each for a iPad App)? How does Xcode adjusts graphics to these screens?
[image: ipad screen]

**EDIT**

Our designer says she has to make 4 graphics for each device (due to density and screensizes) and I need to explain to here, why a retina and a non-retina graphic are enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iPad devices have a screen dimension of 1024x768 **points** (not pixels).

Retina devices have a scaling factor of 2, so you will need to create two sets of graphics, one for non-retina and one for retina; the difference being that the retina images are twice the size in each dimension (i.e. 4 times bigger overall).

So you don't need to worry about each iPad model; simply that it's retina or not.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.
If I would design a graphic for iPad Air (e.g. 1000x1000, 264dpi) wouldnt this make a difference to a iPad Retina since they have other density values, though the pixel are the same?

Comment: @Timm Yes; for non-retina devices that image should be 132dpi.